# How to read all environment variables of a single process using C?

Tags: c, linux, unix

`openproc` provides API for retrieving data from `/proc`. But all examples I found read data about all processes. With `PROC_FILLENV` it should [allocate environment variables](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/procps/openproc.3.en.html):

> allocate `environ` part of `proc_t` and read information from `/proc/#pid/environ`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <proc/readproc.h>

int main(){
  PROCTAB* proc = openproc(PROC_FILLENV);
  proc_t proc_info;

  memset(&proc_info, 0, sizeof(proc_info));
  while (readproc(proc, &proc_info) != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", *proc_info.environ);
  }

  closeproc(proc);
}
```

But it still reads information about all processes. How can I filter processes by PID?

Comment: did you look at the PROC_PID flag?

Comment: https://manpages.debian.org/testing/procps/openproc.3.en.html will tell you.

Comment: Thanks, I've already provided the link in the question. Yes, I read it, but the API usage isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

`PROC_PID` flag and list of PIDs are needed as 2nd argument:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <proc/readproc.h>

// compile with:
// gcc environ.c -lprocps -o bin/environ
int main(){
  pid_t* pidList= NULL;

  pidList = (pid_t*) malloc(sizeof(pid_t)*2 );

  // lookup only processes whose pid is contained in pidlist
  pidList[0] = 1234;
  pidList[1] = 0; // the list is terminated with 0

  PROCTAB* proc = openproc(PROC_PID | PROC_FILLENV, pidList);
  proc_t proc_info;

  memset(&proc_info, 0, sizeof(proc_info));
  while (readproc(proc, &proc_info) != NULL) {
    int i = 0;
    //environ is an array of *char
    while(proc_info.environ[i] != NULL) {
      printf("%s\n", proc_info.environ[i++]);
    }
  }
  closeproc(proc);
  free(pidList);
}
```